# Twitter links in widget don't work?

Tags: links, feed, twitter

I am displaying a twitter feed on my homepage:

http://www.fairwaterrights.com

The feed works fine.  But if I click on a link in the twitter post, it doesn't open.

For instance, instead of opening `http://bit.ly/lNWyT9` in the browser, it tries to open `http://www.fairwaterrights.com/%22http:/bit.ly/lNWyT9%22`.

How can I fix this? Here is the code:

```
<?php
$username = "fairwaterrights"; // Your twitter username.
$limit = "4"; // Number of tweets to pull in.

/* These prefixes and suffixes will display before and after the entire block of tweets. */
$prefix = ""; // Prefix - some text you want displayed before all your tweets.
$suffix = ""; // Suffix - some text you want displayed after all your tweets.
$tweetprefix = "@fairwaterrights "; // Tweet Prefix - some text you want displayed before each tweet.
$tweetsuffix = "<br><br>"; // Tweet Suffix - some text you want displayed after each tweet.

$feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=" . $limit;

function parse_feed($feed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix) {

$feed = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $feed);
$feed = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $feed);
$clean = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);

$amount = count($clean) - 1;

echo $prefix;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {
$cleaner = explode("</content>", $clean[$i]);
echo $tweetprefix;
echo $cleaner[0];
echo $tweetsuffix;
}

echo $suffix;
}

$twitterFeed = file_get_contents($feed);
parse_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is this a plugin you're using? if so, which one is it?

Comment: It's not a plug in, just the code above.

Comment: [This code](http://designwoop.com/2009/06/displaying-your-latest-tweet/) is very similar to yours. Maybe you can compare to figure out the problem

Comment: Thanks for the response. That gives me an error message: > Warning:
> file_get_contents(http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:fairwaterrights&rpp=)
> [function.file-get-contents]: failed
> to open stream: HTTP request failed!
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
> /home/coltrane22/fairwaterrights.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/sidebar.php
> on line 86 Line 86 is: parse_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. I went through and replaced `"` with `'`

```
/* These prefixes and suffixes will display before and after the entire block of tweets. */
$prefix = ""; // Prefix - some text you want displayed before all your tweets.
$suffix = ""; // Suffix - some text you want displayed after all your tweets.
$tweetprefix = "@fairwaterrights&nbsp;"; // Tweet Prefix - some text you want displayed before each tweet.
$tweetsuffix = "<br><br>"; // Tweet Suffix - some text you want displayed after each tweet.

$feed = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:' . $username . '&rpp=' . $limit;

function parse_feed($feed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix) {

$feed = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $feed);
$feed = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $feed);
$clean = explode('<content type=\"html\">', $feed);

$amount = count($clean) - 1;

echo $prefix;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {
$cleaner = explode('</content>', $clean[$i]);
echo $tweetprefix;
echo $cleaner[0];
echo $tweetsuffix;
}

echo $suffix;
}

$twitterFeed = file_get_contents($feed);
parse_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);
?>
```

Comment: Further testing show the code works fine in Safari, it is only a problem in Firefox. Any idea why?